# How do I restrict the WCF service called by an ASP.NET AJAX page to only allow calls for that page?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AjaxControlToolkit DynamicPopulate control that is updated by calls to a WCF service. I know I can check the HttpContext in the service request to see if a user of the page (and thus, the control) is authenticated. However, I don't want anyone clever to be able to call the service directly, even if they're logged in. I want access to the service to be allowed ONLY to requests that are made from the page. Mainly, I don't want anyone to be able to programatically make a large number of calls and then reverse-engineer the algorithm that sits behind the service.

Any clever ideas on how this can be done? Maybe I'm over-thinking this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can add some logic to check the referred to limit access.

Comment: Just a follow up to my own post. Easy way to disable the web service documentation. Add to <system.web> node of config file:
 <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <remove name="Documentation"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>

Comment: If you're using the service for Ajax the Ajax proxy script provides the same information as the WDSL generation would - so even turning the WSDL off (which is is by default for Ajax services) isn't really a help.

Comment: @blowdart: So, by "Ajax proxy script", you mean the generated javascript that's rendered in the page source? I suppose you're right: the service method parameters would be exposed in that script, huh? Bummer. Well, I've realized that I shouldn't really worry about these things until the site has a significant amount of traffic. The problems I'm trying to address are good problems to have, and they can be addressed in a future iteration when necessary.

Comment: Yup that's what I meant - without it, well you can't call the web service :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a different approach. Instead of trying to secure the service to a single page, I just secured the service by checking HttpContext to make sure the user making the request is authenticated. This relies on ASP.NET Compatibility being enabled on the WCF service class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx

Then I have access to HttpContext within the service and can check that the call came from an authenticated user. =D

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't. The complicated answer is you can fudge it with a lot of work, you could for example

1. Rate limit based on the IP of the caller.
2. Drop a cookie based upon the session and rate limit on that.
3. Drop a cookie based upon the page when the page loads and rate limit upon that.

However none is foolproof, and all can go wrong with legitimate requests.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm thinking about implementing that functionality anyway in order to combat user account sharing. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to restrict this to just this one server making the request, you could add a certificate to that server and check for that certificate. However, you probably can't really limit access to just a single *page* calling your service.

You could add a lot of additional elements, like headers etc. - but none will really be totally sound - if someone is determined enough, they'll be able to figure out what you're doing, and replicate that.

So really: why do you need to limit this access this badly?

Comment: The service provides valuable information to a high-value market. 10 million strong consumer base with $8 billion in annual revenue. It seems important to lock it down as tightly as possible to thwart competitors.

Comment: @NovaJoe: ok, makes sense - so can you put a specific certificate on the web server where the requests come from? That would probably be the safest first step, in my opinion.

Comment: Certificates is a good suggestion. Sounds similar to the site-to-site VPNs that I install. One server, one client. Set it and forget it.